# Accidently ran rm -fr in a directory but nothing happened

Tags: rm, recursive

Can someone confirm that running the command `rm -fr` without the `/` does nothing?

I accidentally ran `rm -rf` in my command line and it seemed to do nothing.

I am running a jail-shelled cPanel account on CentOS 6.

Anyway the whole directory is under git control.  After running `rm -fr`, `git status` stated there where no changes.  If there where changes I would have been able to just discard the changes with git.

Just wondering why `rm -fr` didn't do anything.  Does it have to have a file or directory option in order to work?

The linux manual seems to indicate that it needs a file or directory in order to work:

```
rm [OPTION]... FILE...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `rm -fr` does not do anything. The command that deletes a folder is `rm -rf /path/to/folder`.